# Three.js: Bottom of mesh can't be displayed

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have converted a mesh from .obj to json using the official converter (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/obj). The mesh is displayed correctly from one side, but not from the other. I believe the issue is that it only has one side, basically a plane, and therefore all faces and their normals pointing in one direction.

How could I fix this?

**Edit:** I could add the mesh twice, and one time using `material.side = THREE.BackSide;`, but loading it twice doesn't seem like the best option to me.

Comment: Did you try `material.side = THREE.DoubleSide`?

Comment: Ouch, I didn't and completely overlooked that one. Works perfectly ^_^ Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only front faces of triangle primitives are rendered by default when using `WebGLRenderer`. You can override that by setting:

```
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide; // or THREE.BackSide
```

The front face is determined by the *winding order* of the vertices.

If the triangle vertices are specified in counter-clockwise order (CCW), the front face will face towards you; if specified in clockwise order (CW), the front face will face away from you.

This behavior can be changed by the `WebGLRenderer.setFaceCulling()` method, but it is not likely you would find that necessary.

three.js r.75