# how to create face for a 3D mesh

Tags: json, three.js

I have a big problem regarding to create a custom 3D mesh.

```
function handleLoadedGeometry(filename) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF0000});

    for (var i=0; i<filename.length; i++)// loop through the surfaces (roof/wall/ground...)
    {
        var model = filename[i];
        var coordinates = JSON.parse(model.geometry);
        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var coordinates_updated =  _transformCoordinates(coordinates.coordinates[0]);

        for (var j = 0; j<coordinates_updated.vertices.length; j++){// loop through all points

            geometry.vertices.push(
                //new THREE.Vector3(coordinates.coordinates[0][j][0], coordinates.coordinates[0][j][1], coordinates.coordinates[0][j][2])//x,y,z Koordinatenpunkte für Surface 1
                new THREE.Vector3(coordinates_updated.vertices[j][0],coordinates_updated.vertices[j][1],coordinates_updated.vertices[j][2])
            );
            geometry.faces.push(
                new THREE.Face3(0,1,2),
                new THREE.Face3(0,2,3)
            );

            geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        }

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        Scene.scene.add(mesh);
    }
};
```

At the end I get this result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUfY3.jpg)

When I add **material.side = THREE.DoubleSide** the WallSurface looks very well but the roof and groundsurfaces dont.
Do I have to do a triangulation?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693850/three-js-bottom-of-mesh-cant-be-displayed/36697479#36697479) is the issue.

Comment: No it doens´t. I guess this error occurs because of wrong faces. I have 3DFaces and on each loop I have different numbers of vertices... So I figured out that if I have three vertices I have to create one face (0,1,2) if I have four vertices I have to create two meshes (0,1,2),(0,2,3) and so on. Can I do this in a switch case operation? switch(number of vertices) case 3 (create face(0,1,2)); case 4(create face(0,1,2), create face(0,2,3)); and so on! Is this the right way to handle this problem?

Comment: How you choose to code it is up to you.

Comment: I created the face but I still get lines from vertices to point of origin. What is going on? Something must be wrong regarding the faces

Comment: Ok its done  there was a mistake with my switch operation!